# Resources for Probabilstic forecasting

Tags: time-series, forecasting, probabilistic-forecasts

I was planning on learning probabilistic forecasting and im completely lost. Suggest some online resources. I have started with Probabilistic Forecasting and Bayesian Data Assimilation but its a bit too advanced for me.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What preliminary material do you know so far? Do you know forecasting, machine learning, or regression of any kind?

Comment: Yes im familiar with ML and point forecasts and have worked different projects as well